# estoy creando un acortador y quiero agregarle un caracter despues que genere el string en randon por ej .ru .eu .com que seria dominio.com/oihoi.eu

Tags: php

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

quiero que despues de cada string generado me agregue de forma aleatoria un .ru .re .eu ej sdubudfy/eu

Answer (score 0):

Sencillo. Armas un arreglo con los sufijos que quieres usar, luego usas una función para seleccionar un índice del arreglo de forma aleatoria y pum, concatenas.

Probé con este código, modificado a partir del que compartiste:

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    
    // Armar una lista de los valores que quieres
    $dominios = ["ru", "re", "eu"];
    
    // Hacer un pseudoaleatorio que seleccione un valor entre la cantidad de valores de tu arreglo
    $sufijoAleatorio = $dominios[rand(0, count($dominios) -1 )];
    
    return $randomString . "." . $sufijoAleatorio;
}

print_r(generateRandomString());
```

Comment: todo genial funcioando a la perfeccion thank you

Comment: @JulianRosario recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada con el tick justo bajo los votos de la respuesta! Así otros sabrán que está solucionado y usarán la solución